# not able authenticate in login

Tags: reactjs, axios

I could not authenticate and i getting the response, but I'm using sweet alert to show respectively, but one sweet alert is showing in both cases (i.e. error one sweet alert).also I'm getting "error.response is not defined". Please help in this.

```
export const authlogin = (email, password) =>{
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(authStart());
        axios.post('http://172.61.24.51:8050/api/user/login/', {
            email: email, 
            password: password
        }).then(res => {
                const token = res.data.token;
                if (token) {
                    dispatch(authEnd());
                    swal({
                        title: "Logged in!",
                        text: "Welcome back again. We missing you.",
                        icon: "success",
                        timer: 5000,
                        button: false
                    })
                    console.log(token);
                    const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600 * 1000);
                    localStorage.setTime('expirationDate', expirationDate);
                    dispatch(authSuccess(token));
                    dispatch(checkAuthTimeout(3600));
                }               
        }) 
        .catch(function(error) {
            if (error) {
            dispatch(authFail(error));
                swal({
                    title: "Not logged in!",
                    text: "This is not you account?",
                    icon: "error",
                    timer: 2000,
                    button: false
                })
            }
        });
        // .catch (err => {
        //     dispatch(authFail(err))
        // })
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `authFail()` reducer, you're probably trying to look at `error.response` which is not defined.

Comment: @FrankerZ i have already defined in reducer 

```const authFail = (state, action) => {
    return updateObject(state, {
        token: action.error,
        loading: false
    });
}
```

Comment: Is your `authEnd()` reducer expecting an action?

Comment: @FrankerZ: here is my authEnd. Please check
```
const authEnd = (state, action) => {
    return updateObject(state, {
        error: null,
        loading: false
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first alert is shown because if you have some kind of errors in your `then()` callback it will be caught by the `catch()` callback.
So for example if you have an empty or missed property here `const token = res.data.token;` will cause the catch to be called.

Also the message `error.response is not defined` could be caused for the similar reasons or for some CORS browser restrictions.

See the example taken from the [official axsios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors)

```
axios.get('/user/12345')
 .catch(function (error) {
   if (error.response) {
     // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
     // that falls out of the range of 2xx
     console.log(error.response.data);
     console.log(error.response.status);
     console.log(error.response.headers);
   } else if (error.request) {
     // The request was made but no response was received
     // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
     // http.ClientRequest in node.js
     console.log(error.request);
   } else {
     // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
     console.log('Error', error.message);
   }
     console.log(error.config);
});
```

Comment: I could not find any console.log in console.

Comment: You have to write `console.log` to log output in console